# how to save the offset of current scroll position for Jquery Mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to save the offset of the current value of the page in a global variable and trying to use it for scrolling back to the same position when page is reloaded .

Here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", '#outerPage', function(){
    $(document).on('vclick','#outerPage',function(e){
   //alert('yo i am clickable now'); 

    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
   storePosition.topCoordinate = relY;   
});
    var  positionY = storePosition.topCoordinate ;     
    if(positionY !== null) {

        setTimeout(function () {
        $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll = positionY;
    }, 10); 
    }
});

var storePosition = {
    topCoordinate : null
}
</script>
```

Here I am trying to store the offset in `storePosition.topCoordinate` then use it in the function to set the page scroll . but my variable is always set to null I dont understand why this is happening .

**UPDATE**

For now I am using the a script something like this

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#outerPage', function () {
    $('a').on('vclick', function () {
        console.log('its done Boy');
        localStorage.setItem('scrolls', 0);

    });

});

/*$(window).on('unload', function() {
    console.log(window.location.pathname);
    console.log(window.location.pathname);
    console.log( "Bye now!" );
})*/

$(document).on('pageinit', '#outerPage', function () {
    $(document).on("scrollstop", function () {
        var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
        var relY = window.scrollY;
        localStorage.setItem('scrolls', relY);
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("scrolls"));
    });

});

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", '#outerPage', function () {
    var positionY = localStorage.getItem("scrolls");
    if (positionY != null) {
        $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll = positionY;
    }
});
```

So I am saving the value in a localStorage and clearing it up when I  change page like when I click on link   tag I know this is not the right solution :P. I was trying to use .unload() but it was not clearing the LocalStorage event when the same page was refreshed

Please help me out with this

Thanks & Regards

Comment: @Omar here is my code

Comment: 1) using `pagebeforeshow` to bind event isn't a good idea. 2) you're attaching `vclick` to _page_ and _page_'s parent is `body` or `pagecontainer` ;) 3) declare global var outside any function in order to make it accessible.

Comment: @omar okay I am on it :D

Comment: @Omar http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/x00t70dt/3/  here is an updated fiddle I did all the thing you said and still the global variable is becoming null

Comment: I'm working on it. I'll need to update `$.mobile.navigate.history.stack` with last scroll value. better than global vars.

Comment: @Omar oh okay . Yeah I saw that in one of your post but did not understood properly :P

Comment: I've a rather complicated code 90% complete http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bLxch7o3/

Comment: @Omar -- Man, i cant wait for Version 2 of JQM. :)))

Comment: @Omar oh this is so kool! wish I could code like you :D

Comment: @Tasos same here, I hope they come out with more felixbe version :)

Comment: @Vikram you can code better than me :) the demo isn't yet ready, I need to test it thoroughly.

Comment: @Omar yeah all this workarounds we are doing are a pain -- Vikram i assume if Omar is working on the issue my answer is not the one so i'm deleting it M8.

Comment: @Tasos my workaround doesn't necessarily mean it's perfect, its a "workaround". Keep your answer, undelete it.

Comment: @omar I got to learn a lot about Jquery Mobile internal events from your workaround and most of the time these events are not mentioned in the JQM docs . Thanks a Lot man but still I think I know so less . Do you suggest me to read any book for JQM specially .

Comment: @tasos please do not delete your answer

Comment: @Vikram read docs + _trial and error_, this is the way to master any language ;)

Answer (score 3):

On one of my projects i use this code to remember the last scrolled position on a page.

**Demo (just scroll on the list, got to page 2 and come back)**

http://jsfiddle.net/ukzuvtyh/

**Jquery code for remmebring last position**

```
var storePosition = {     /// initializing the storeposition
    topCoordinate : null
}


 storePosition.topCoordinate =  $(this).offset().top;   /// storing the position


if(storePosition.topCoordinate !== 0) {   // if we are at the top no point doing anything

 $("html, body").animate({"scrollTop":  storePosition.topCoordinate}, 500);

 }
```

If you see that on some pages when you go back the scroll to the last position is off by some pixels subtract or add to get the exact position. It will be ok after that. You will need to judge a little before the right amount. - 60 indigates 60 pixels minus on the scroll. I had this issue, don't know why so its a fix

```
$("html, body").animate({"scrollTop":  storePosition.topCoordinate - 60}, 500);
```

Comment: you dont need any extra plugins for this, `$("body").animate({"scrollTop": number}, 500);` is enough ;)

Comment: Ok i changed it, but wait and see when we get another question on performance using JQ animate. ;)

Comment: Where on internet Explorer? change ($("body").animate) to ($("html, body").animate)) The Left to Right scroll doesnt seem to be affected in JQM but i dont know what content you have ---  http://jsfiddle.net/fw0L1qgm/

Comment: @Tasos actually in my website going to next page means a new URl is being fired unlikely the native Jquery Mobile pages that are different pages on the same url .

Comment: Cant you store the position in a cookie -- anyway, construct a jfiddle cause it seems you have many issues to resolve

Comment: @tasos yes thats what I am doing .  See my update in the question I am storing it in localStorage  in the and then using it to scroll but How can I clear it when I change to different page