# How can I mantain my position on the page on refresh (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I know that this is only possible with AJAX, but i've never worked with AJAX... On my website you can keep a list of the cards that you have from the game Magic, this is quite the list. You have to press a button to add a card, each card has this button and when you add it, It will add the card to your list then refresh and be at the top of the page again. How can i make it that it keeps it's position?

Inside of the red squares you can press add or remove : http://prntscr.com/5uq6ak

Functions.php (I'll only show 2 functions, remove and add cards)

```
//Add card to collection
function addCardToCollection($conn, $userID, $cardID){
//Checks if the cards is already added for this user
    $queryGetCard = 'SELECT user_id, card_id FROM collection WHERE user_id = '.$userID.' AND card_id = '.$cardID;
    $checkCollection = $conn->query($queryGetCard);
    if($checkCollection->fetch_assoc() > 0){return 'Deze kaart hebt u al.';}

//Adds card to the database
    $queryAddCard = 'INSERT INTO collection (user_id, card_id) VALUES ('.$userID.','.$cardID.')';
    if($conn->query($queryAddCard)){return 'Kaart toegevoegd.';}
    else{return 'Kaart niet toegevoegd.';}
}

//Remove card from collection
function removeCardFromCollection($conn, $userID, $cardID){
//Checks if the cards is in the collection
    $queryGetCard = 'SELECT user_id, card_id FROM collection WHERE user_id = '.$userID.' AND card_id = '.$cardID;
    $checkCollection = $conn->query($queryGetCard);
    if($checkCollection->fetch_assoc() == 0){return 'Deze kaart hebt u nog niet.';}

//Remove card from the database
    $queryAddCard = 'DELETE FROM collection WHERE user_id = '.$userID.' AND card_id = '.$cardID;
    if($conn->query($queryAddCard)){return 'Kaart verwijderd uit uw collectie.';}
    else{return 'Kaart niet verwijderd uit uw collectie.';}
}
```

Set.php (The buttons for add and delete)

```
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $cardsHTML.='<br><b>Deze kaart heb ik...
    <a href="' . $baseURL . 'set.php?id=' . $_GET['id'] . '&cardID=' . $value['id'] . '&collection=add">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green"></div>
    </a> |
    <a href="' . $baseURL . 'set.php?id=' . $_GET['id'] . '&cardID=' . $value['id'] . '&collection=remove">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red"></div>
    </a>
    </b>';
}
```

Comment: Will need to store game state somewhere ... localStorage or server.

Comment: how...? I dont have any knowledge on that

Comment: Depends on how position is determined. Overall question is pretty vague

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about using JS to do this?

Note: This requires the JQuery plugin, there are many CDN you can get it from though, with google being one of the most reliable [Here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var storePosition = {     /// initializing the storeposition
        topCoordinate : null
    }


     storePosition.topCoordinate =  $(this).offset().top;   /// storing the position


    if(storePosition.topCoordinate !== 0){   // if we are at the top no point doing anything

     $("html, body").animate({"scrollTop":  storePosition.topCoordinate}, 500);


        }
});
```

courtesy of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036776/how-to-save-the-offset-of-current-scroll-position-for-jquery-mobile-page)

Also just a note... PLEASE stop using non parameterized queries. consider using MySQLi as its not much of a step up from MySql syntax and will give you some good practice with object orientated programming.

Comment: Yeahh... i didn't made I'm just an intern that has to do these little fixes, Where should I put the code cuz I really don't know

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and guess that you have Jquery running on the site, in which case wrap that code in a <script></script> Tag on the page

Answer (score 0):

During an insert add column with timestamp .
And get data ascending order of timestamp.
Display the card.it will not change.